# javascript: How to repeatedly call the function itself?

Tags: javascript

I want to repeatedly count time and update the current time every one minute. My code doesn't work. Firebug console says the final line function `getStatus()` is not defined. How to call this function repeatedly?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(function() {   
     getStatus();
    });

    function getStatus() {
      var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
      var nonce = $('#_wpnonce').val();
      jQuery.ajax({
        url : ajaxurl,
        data : {action: "update_edit_lock", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce },
        success: function(response) {
          if(response == "false") {
            alert("failed")
          }
          else {
            $("#message").html(response)
          }
        }
        });
      setTimeout("getStatus()",60000);
    }
    },(jQuery));
```

Comment: You want setInterval. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is getStatus is wrapped in another callback. either do `window.getStatus = function(){}`, or turn your code to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var getStatus = function() {
      var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
      var nonce = $('#_wpnonce').val();
      jQuery.ajax({
        url : ajaxurl,
        data : {action: "update_edit_lock", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce },
        success: function(response) {
          if(response == "false") {
            alert("failed")
          }
          else {
            $("#message").html(response)
          }
        }
        });
      setTimeout(getStatus,60000);
    };

    $(function() {   
     getStatus();
    });

},(jQuery));
```

Passing a string to `setTimeout` will make it `eval` the string, which you should avoid, and generally not required by your code

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval(getStatus, 60000)` instead perhaps, but otherwise you should use `setTimeout(getStatus, 60000)`.  Do not use a string as the function callback but rather the named function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval(function, milliseconds)`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var getStatus = function() {
        var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
        var nonce = $('#_wpnonce').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "update_edit_lock",
                post_id: post_id,
                nonce: nonce
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == "false") {
                    alert("failed")
                } else {
                    $("#message").html(response)
                }
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(getStatus, 1000);
}, (jQuery));
```